# ColdFusion - How to output single quotes into a text field?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.

I can't find a means to successfully output a single quote into a text field.

I create form fields using a CFSCRIPT user defined function. (I've minimized the options for the sake of simplicity for this example.)

When my output contains a single quote, the text field gets totally screwed up, be sure to run the example and view the HTML.  I have tried using PreserveSingleQuotes() every conceivable way possible.

```
// USE EITHER STRING
MyString = "This string works fine.";
MyString = "This single quote's the problem!";
writeOutput(createInputBox(MyString));

// CREATE TEXT INPUT
function createInputBox(Value) {
    LOCAL.Properties = " value='#preserveSingleQuotes(ARGUMENTS.Value)#'";
    LOCAL.Item = "<input size='50' type='text' #LOCAL.Properties# />";
    return LOCAL.Item;
}
```

Do you know of a solution?
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ANSWER

Get rid of the preserveSingleQuotes() function, as it does nothing outside of a SQL block. (Thanks Adam!).

```
LOCAL.Properties = " value='#ARGUMENTS.Value#'";
```

Then, get rid of the single quotes and replaced with escaped double quotes:

```
LOCAL.Properties = " value=""#ARGUMENTS.Value#""";
```

This will still choke on strings like this though:

```
MyString = "This is my F#@'''""$":""ing  problem!";
```

So, add the htmlEditFormat() function like this:

```
LOCAL.Properties = " value=""#htmlEditFormat(ARGUMENTS.Value)#""";
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: I just noticed you've added an extension to the answer in your question. That's not how Stack Overflow works: You should instead **create your own answer**, or **edit the closest existing answer** to make a complete solution, then mark that as accepted.

Comment: I will do so next time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single quote should not give you a problem in an attribute value in HTML, unless:
* you're not quoting the attribute values, eg:

```
<input value=#myvar#>
```

The solution here is to quote your attributes, eg:

```
<input value="#myvar#">
```

or
* you are quoting your attributes, but are using single quotes :

```
<input value='#myVar#'>
```

Will end up being:

```
<input value='value with a ' in it'>
```

This - of course is invalid mark-up: the browser sees the value as 'value with a ', and the rest of it is just garbage.

If you need to do this:
* switch to using double-quote delimiters
* use htmlEditFormat() around your variable value (this will escape embedded double-quotes).

To troubleshoot this sort of thing, ALWAYS look at the HTML source.  This will help you work out what's going on.

NB: to everyone mentioning preserveSingleQuote(): this function does NOTHING outside of a CFQUERY block.  So it's not going to help here.

Comment: Adam, if you remove the preserveSingleQuotes() function, my function doesn't work. When you escape the double quotes, it works fine.  However, it doesn't work perfectly until the htmlEditFormat() function is used along with the escaped quotes.

Comment: Ah, dunno what "doesn't work" means without you qualifying that by telling me what it *does* do instead of working.  Trust me: preserveSingleQuotes() does nothing at all in the code you had, so if the behaviour changed, it was down to something ELSE you changed @ the same time.  Actually: *don't* trust me... try it for yourself (a homework assignment!) have a mess around with preserveSingleQuotes() & read the docs on it (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cbf.html) and get comfortable with how it works.  Then you'll be ready for "next time"

Comment: My function didn't work with or without preserveSingleQuotes(), so any argument pertaining to that function is completely irrelevant. Please read my answer above.  You can run my code from above. I certainly ran it trying to figure out the problem.  I wouldn't waste your time using examples that couldn't be run from a simple copy/paste.  Thanks for your answer and info!!!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're experiencing relates to the character delimiters for the value field. If you use single quotes as field delimiters, and a single quote is provided by your app, there will be a problem. One ways I've dealt with this in the past is to use double quotes for the field. The line shown below should plug into your code:

```
LOCAL.Properties = " value=""#preserveSingleQuotes(ARGUMENTS.Value)#""";
```

The approach shown by Sean Kimball is equally valid. Depending on the situation, I've used both approaches.

There was another comment re: preserveSingleQuotes. I can't say that I've used this outside of database calls, but if it works for you in this situation, I've learned something, too!

Comment: And this approach will work for me in the future.  Okay, you have to escape the quotes with quotes.  Crazy!!! It works though.  Thanks!

Comment: The key to the correctness of this answer is NOT the use of preserveSingleQuotes(). The key is escaping the quotes and double quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have removed the preserveSingleQuotes... code blinders must be on today.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I would be helpful though if you would explain what your changes, not just provide working code. Most people learn by seeing code and having the explanation pointed out explicitly. Again, thanks for your help!!!

Comment: nykash, you can edit your answer to update the code - you should see an edit link between link and flag?

Comment: Peter & Evik - Thanks for the advice, I'll provide better answers (and edits) in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
// CREATE TEXT INPUT
function createInputBox(Value) {
    LOCAL.Properties = ' value="' &#preserveSingleQuotes(ARGUMENTS.Value)#& '"';
    LOCAL.Item = '<input size="50" type="text" #LOCAL.Properties# />';
    return LOCAL.Item;
}

// USE EITHER STRING
MyString = "This string works fine.";
MyString = "This single quote's the problem!";
writeOutput(createInputBox(MyString));
```